# linearlayout element and their position

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a linearLayout with 2 elements, a textView and a imagebutton, I would like to center in the linearlayout the textView and right-aligment for the imageButto, but both of them are at left.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:background="@color/usualBike"
>    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usesLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/tituloUsos"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />   

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/disconnect"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_logout" />

</LinearLayout>
```

how can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you particular about `LinearLayout`? if not why don't you try with `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="@color/usualBike"
    >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usesLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/tituloUsos"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/disconnect"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_logout" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: LinearLayout basically to arrange control in linear manner, you have to be flexible in choosing the correct layout(i.e. here RelativeLayout), +1.

Answer (score 0):

try layout_gravity instead of gravity

Comment: I tried this but it still fails, edited my post with your suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usesLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="tituloUsos"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/disconnect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/usesLabel"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```